# Change query from solr4 to solr6

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I have a solr search in solr4. This is the url:
solr.int/bweb-solr/coreX/select?q=Tramitaci%C3%B3n&wt=json&indent=true

But when migrate this to solr6 I need add the field in the search to obtains the sames results, ex:
solr.int/bweb-solr/coreX/select?q=status:Tramitaci%C3%B3n&wt=json&indent=true

Can change this option to dont use the field in q paramter?
I have the same default field.

Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/change df parameter in your select request handler, new value of df will be "status". After this you don't need to specify field name with every request. Solr will consider "status" as a default search field for every request.